# If I create a select dropdown using jQuery then .change() method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Javascript code is like that

```
for(var k in totalimage)
{
   $('#country').append('<select><option>'+country[k].name+'</option></select>');
}
```

If I change the selected country, I want to show only that country's cities in the city dropdown that also binds using jQuery but `.change()` method is not working.

I want to upload multiple image at same time. And also I need country and city select box for every image that I will be selected. That's why I am creating select box using jQuery for every image that I will select.

Comment: 1) Where is your "change" method? 2) How are you selecting anything? There are no unique id's, classes or just about anything to select the dynamicly created content. 3) Why are you creating complete new selection fields for every loop instead of only adding options?

Comment: You also appear to me making a new `<select>` for each item.

Comment: Can you please share html also ?

Comment: Refer to @waleed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in JS section and then call let in the element using `onChange` attribute

Like that

```
function displaySelectedCountry() {
    // your code
}
```

Then using this function inside your element using `onChange` like this

```
<select onChange="displaySelectedCountry()">
```

or you can use this way. Give the element id for example called "`js-displaySelectedCountry`" and then in javascript section use change event like below

```
$(document).on('change', '#js-displaySelectedCountry', function () {
    // your code here!
});
```